# react and axios POST throws an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parsed is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm baffled what I'm doing wrong in my code. The GET call gets resolved, but when I try to do a POST call to the same server I get an error. My POST endpoint works fine with Postman.

**apiConnection.js**

```
function get(data){
  return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/questions", 
    {
      params:data.payload
    }, {
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
    }
  })
}

function post(data){
  console.log(data.payload) //my payload is received here
  return axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/answer", {
      params:data.payload
    }, {
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
      }
    }
  )
}

export { get, post }
```

**Here is the error I get in the console**

[image]

And here is how I make the call in react

**index.js**

**GET (Receives response normally)**

```
import { get, post } from "apiConnection.js"
...
componentDidMount(){
    const data = {
      payload: {
        linkId: getSlug()
      }
    }
    get(data).then((result) => {
      this.setState({reportId: result.data.report.id});
    })
  }
```

**POST (Throws error)**

```
vote(userVote){
    const data = {
      payload: {
        reportId: this.state.reportId,
      }
    }
    
    post(data).then((result)=>{
      this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].vote = userVote
    });
  }
```

Comment: axios.post() you need to send body/data instead of params, that could be the issue

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem. Initially I tried `return axios.post("http://endpoint", data.payload)` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Try setting devtool to 'inline-source-map' to get a more precise error message with which file the error occured etc, instead of just from bundle.js. Do you know where ```parsed``` is suppose to be defined?

Comment: @Sandsten thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and what I got was that error comes from `isURLSameOrigin.js:57` which led me to search for answers around that. That led me nowhere. Anyways I found the bug, which I wrote about in the answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the culprit of the issue but if someone can add more information about it, it might be helpful for others.

In my question, for brevity, I changed the request URL from imported constants to hardcoded links.

In my code, I have a variable for both **GET** and **POST**

```
return axios.post(apiEndpoints[data.ep], data.payload)
```

I import the endpoint variables like so

```
import * as apiEndpoints from './apiEndpoints';
```

**apiEndpoints.js**

```
const server = 'http://localhost:8080/'
const api_version = 'api/'
const base_url = server+api_version;

export const EP_QUESTIONS = base_url+'questions';
export const EP_ANSWER = base_url+'answer';
```

For some unknown reason `EP_ANSWER` throws the error even though I'm not making a typo when I define `data.ep` (`data.ep` has `EP_ANSWER`, which
I checked a million times)

The solution was to just change `EP_ANSWER` to `EP_ANS` and everything worked as expected.

No idea why this is the case. It might be some global variable or a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and noted @Ando's response.

So, knowing that I first tried a hard coded URL, it worked.

I then successfully did url.toString() and it worked.

Not sure why but Javascript seems to treat a an object string differently than a true string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32712977)